# How to construct a bicentric quadrilateral

Tags: geometry

A bicentric quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in the circle $k_1(O_1; R)$ and circumscribes the circle $k_2(O_2; r)$. How to construct it in GeoGebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Poncelet's closure theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poncelet%27s_closure_theorem) any point on the circumcircle can be a vertex of a bicentric quadrilateral. Therefore choose a point on the circumcircle, construct from it a tangent to the incircle, find the other intersection point of the tangent with circumcircle and repeat the process until the quadrilateral closures.

Note: the distance between the centers of the in- and circumcircle is a function of their radii! The procedure above works only if the distance is chosen [correctly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_polygon). Otherwise there exists no bicentric quadrilateral.

Comment: Thank you for the response! How do I begin? What to construct first?

Comment: I would assume you should choose values of the radii, compute the distance and construct the circles. Then proceed as proposed in the answer. I am however not an expert in `GeoGebra`.

Comment: How can I choose values of the radii? It will be helpful if the distance between the centers of the in- and circumcircle is a real number.

Comment: In the answer I gave  a link to the formula connecting the radii and the distance. Probably most simple way is to choose arbitrarily the circumradius and the distance. Then inradius can be immediately computed. In my answer I assumed that all values are real.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help! I noticed that if $V$ is the intersection point of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$, $V,O_1$ and $O_2$ are collinear points. Can we show this?

Comment: I would suggest you to post this as a new question.